# SQL Server Select the most recent record only

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table tat looks like this:

Table1

```
ID Date       TermDate Cancel
1  20140101   99999999 20140102
1  20140101   20130102 20140102

2  20140108   20130102 20140102
2  20140101   99999999 20140102

3  20140101   99999999 20140102
3  20140101   99999999 20140102
3  20140101   99999999 20140709
```

What I want to do is, to group by each ID and select only the most recent record.
First I need to check the Date column, from there if a record is more recent then I do not need to check the other columns, in this case, it is ID #2.

If the Date column is the same for same ID, then I want to compare the Cancel column, whichever is the most recent then that record should be shown only, in this case it is ID 3.

If both Date and Cancel columns are the same, then I need to compare the TermDate column and the most recent should be displayed, in this case it is ID #1. All columns are int type.

Basically the result should be:

```
ID Date       TermDate Cancel
1  20140101   99999999 20140102
2  20140108   20130102 20140102
3  20140101   99999999 20140709
```

I am not the best person with self join tables and really not sure how to get started with this... what I currently do is: I copy the table into Excel file and then do the job manually... 
I am thinking to use CASE Statement but really do not know how to convert my logic to SQL proper code, here is my pseducode:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Date > DATE THEN SELECT the greater Date 
        CASE WHEN Date = Date THEN SELECT the grater Cancel
        ELSE WHEN Date = Date AND Cancel = Cancel THEN SELECT the grater TermDate END)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
```

I don't even know how to make the table look like the above with case statement.

Please let me know what is the best way to do this... I searched online with no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` function to assign a rank to each row within one ID based on your ordering and get the first one for each ID:

```
select id, [date], termdate, cancel from
    (select id, [date], termdate, cancel,
        dense_rank() over (partition by id order by [date] desc, cancel desc, termdate desc) rank
    from table1) X
where rank = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28cfc/1)

Comment: I would have never figured it out with the dense_rank(), I will definitely try your solution and let you know the result. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: One question please, does the dense_rank only works with varchar? Since my fields are all int, does that mean I need to Cast them to varchar? Thanks again.

Comment: No, it works with all data types. I updated my Fiddle - it has a new link in the answer now.